# search by substring in mongodb from powershell

Tags: mongodb, powershell, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

I am trying to make the following mongodb query on powershell:

```
collection.find({"field1":"valueA","field2":"valueB","field3":/subStr_ValueC/})
```

I tried to do the following but doesn't work:

```
$query = @{
            "field1" = $notification["A"]
            "field2" = $notification["B"]
            "field3" = "/" + $notification["C"] + "/"
        }

$cursor = $collection.find([MongoDB.Driver.QueryDocument]$query)
```

Any idea, how to do this?

thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
$query = @{
  'field1' = $notification['A']
  'field2' = $notification['B']
  'field3' = @{ '$regex' = '.*' + $notification['C'] + '.*'; '$options' = 'i' }
}

$cursor = $collection.find([MongoDB.Driver.QueryDocument]$query)
```

Comment: what do you have in `$notification["C"]`? Try with `"field3" = @{ "$regex" = ".*"; "$options" = "i" }` to see if this works.

Comment: field3 is a string. It is giving me this error Duplicate keys '' are not allowed in hash literals. using your 2 suggestions

Comment: I forgot that it tries to evaluate things in double quotes. Try the updated version (with single quotes).

Comment: Yep that worked, why id did not work with double quotes? also I'm wondering if the "i" option is taking more resources as it will compare also capital leters?

Comment: Great. You can omit `'$options' = 'i'` if you want case sensitivity. When you are using double quotes powershell replaces `$regex` and `$options` with respective variable values (in this case no variable `$regex` and `$option` was there and it resulted in an empty string)